# How to match the background color of a TabLayout to the Toolbar?

Tags: android

I'm trying to setup a TabLayout, but its background color is white and I'm not sure, how to change it in the xml layout. I tried googling it, but I've only found, how to set the background color programatically.

This is how it looks:

[image]

I tried adding the tag `app:tabBackground` and making it the primary color but it looks strange: [image]

How can I make it look like a smooth background with the primary color?

Comment: I think this is the way it looks on newer API levels. There's this shadow-y effect. On API 16 or something it's just the same color.

Answer (score 2):

Try this on your actionbar,

```
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your layout xml, but I believe the background is set on the tabs, so depending on your viewpager it is different. On newer APIs, there is an automatic elevation for the toolbar so you may need to set that to 0.

```html
app:elevation="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in the onCreate() method of activity

```
getActionBar().setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00AA5C")));
```